# Align text to top of header using fancyhdr

Tags: vertical-alignment, fancyhdr, geometry

I'm trying to get the left heading to appear at the top left corner of the header, but I cannot seem to get it moved there. How can this be achieved using fancyhdr? I tried updating

```
\lhead{\textbf{Citation:}}
```

to

```
\lhead{\textbf{Citation:} \vfill}
```

With no success (among many other unsuccessful attempts)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}


%\setlength{\hoffset}{} 
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-.41in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7.52in}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{3in}
\setlength{\headsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\headheight}{1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{-.5in}

\pagestyle{fancy}

%HEADING TO SHIFT TO TOP
\lhead{\textbf{Citation:}}
\rhead{Page \thepage of \pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of setting the page geometry using `\setlength`, you should use the functionality provided by [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry). Then, if you wish to *raise* content into place, use `\raisebox{<len>}[0pt][0pt]{<stuff>}`.

Comment: @Werner, `\raisebox` will mostlikely solve my issue. Why is it inadvisable to use `\setlength` to modify the doc?

Comment: That functionality is provided by [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry), so if you're loading `geometry`, use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple  `\parbox`, specifying it height, will do the job. Since you load the package, I converted your layout specifications to `geometry` as well as I could (the horizontal parameters are  inconsistent: are you sure you want a `\marginparsep`of **3** inches?):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage[headheight = 1in, headsep = \baselineskip, top = 1.5in, , left = 0.59in, textwidth = 7.52 in, showframe]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%HEADING TO SHIFT TO TOP
\lhead{ \parbox[][\headheight][t]{2cm}{\textbf{Citation:}}}
\rhead{\parbox[][\headheight][b]{2cm}{\raggedleft Page\,\thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \vtop to \dimexpr \headheight-\baselineskip\relax {...} also works.

Comment: Sure, but that's a plain  TeX construction.

Comment: This also shifts the Page counter up, on the right header. I need that value positioned at the bottom. Also, just out of curiosity, is there any advantage to using `\parbox` vs `raisebox`?

Comment: @DJK: I've updated the code. Another  `\parbox[}[\headheight][b]` was enough. As to your question, with `\raisebox`, you have to calculate by how much you raise, which depends on what you raise (fontsize, multiline or not, &c.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to leave the baseline in place, use `\raisebox`.

Note, if you add too much space, fancyhdr will increase `\headheight`, possibly every page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}


%\setlength{\hoffset}{} 
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-.41in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7.52in}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{3in}
\setlength{\headsep}{\normalbaselineskip}% \baselineskip changes depending on the font size
\setlength{\headheight}{1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{-.5in}

\pagestyle{fancy}

%HEADING TO SHIFT TO TOP
\lhead{\raisebox{\dimexpr \headheight-\baselineskip}{\textbf{Citation:}}}
\rhead{Page \thepage~of \pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I may have not made this clear sorry, but I  need only the left header shifted to the top of the header, This moves the rule and page numbering to the top as well

Comment: Done.  I was actually try to avoid \raisebox as too obvious.

Comment: Ha, I guess you have much to learn about a language when something is too obvious